# git: 'http-push' is not a git command. fatal: git-http-push failed

Tags: linux, git

I am trying to push to a repository over https, but am receiving the following error:

```
[root@localhost systemevents]# git push
git: 'http-push' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
fatal: git-http-push failed
```

I am not checking the SSL certificate (`git config --global http.sslVerify false`). This on a Redhat Enterprise Linux 5 virtual machine, a fresh installation, running in VMWare Player. Git was installed in the following manner:

```
./configure --with-openssl --with-expat=/opt/expat --with-curl=/opt --prefix=/usr/local
make all
make install
```

Libssh2 (v1.4.2) was installed from source; Curl and Expat were installed in the following manner:

```
#Curl v7.26
./configure --with-libssh2 --enable-shared --prefix=/opt
make; make install

# Expat v2.1
./configure --prefix=/opt/expat
make; make install
```

The versions of these programs in the yum repository I have access to are rather old, too old for `git push` apparently. The error message is rather confusing to me, not sure what to do with it. I am able to clone and pull over HTTP without problem.

Comment: Do you have some kind of read/write issue on the repo, as mentioned in http://talk.maemo.org/showthread.php?t=58301 ? What is the git version on the remote server you are pushing to?

Comment: @VonC I don't think so, the error I posed here is all that shows up for me unlike the maemo link. I don't have access to info about the remote server currently, I can get details from the admin on Monday. I'm thinking it's a problem on the client side because I'm able to push from my Windows XP host machine without problems.

Comment: What's the address of your remote in your repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this exact same error on Windows. I tried a few different versions of git all with the same error. I eventually tracked down the problem as being caused by libcurl not being found or not being in the right place. In my case, I copied the libcurl.dll from the Git\bin folder to the Git\libexec\git-core folder. I then had to rename it to libcurl-4.dll. My guess is something similar is happening in your case as far as finding the libcurl shared library in *nix-land.

Comment: This is long enough ago that I don't remember whether this was resolved or worked around somehow. Anyhow, this is probably correct.