# Git http-push is not a git-command

Tags: git

Very new to git and just setting up based on tutorial instructions:

```
git init
git add --all
git commit -m "Initial Commit"
git remote add origin http://user@server/trunk.git
```

Which all go through fine

However, when I run:

```
git push origin master
```

I get the following error:

```
git: 'http-push' is not a git-command. See 'git --help'.
```

I'm running git version 1.6.0.2 in opensuse

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any particular reason for using such an old version?

Comment: is libcurl installed? see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11275134/33499)

Comment: I just used the opensuse package manager and this was the version it gave me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git help http-push` (on Git 2.1.2) tells me:

> NOTE: This command is temporarily disabled if your libcurl is older than
>   7.16, as the combination has been reported not to work and sometimes
>   corrupts repository.

A few things I'd try:

- Use HTTPS or SSH instead of HTTP
- Find out your libcurl version and update it if necessary
- [Update Git](http://git-scm.com/) if `git help http-push` doesn't work either

1.6.0.2 is [six years old](https://github.com/git/git/tree/v1.6.0.2) by the way, so I'd consider upgrading it regardless.

Comment: I had libcurl 7.19 installed but updating git works fine

Comment: If you're interested in the differences between Git version, you can find them [here](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/Documentation/RelNotes).